# Android BottomNavigationView with Splash Screen Back Stack Issue

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph, android-bottomnavigationview, android-splashscreen

So I setup my `BottomNavigationView` (like [here](https://youtu.be/Covu3fPA1nQ)) using Navigation Component library and everything works fine, every tab can keep their back stacks. However, if I add a Splash screen (`Fragment`) and:

1. Set it as start destination (`popUpInclusive` set to true already)
2. Create action from **SplashFragment** to the first tab **HomeFragment**

then all the tabs no longer keep their back stacks, plus the navigation becomes weird:

Splash -> Home (first tab) ->  Me (second tab) -> Home -> press back, it goes back to Me instead of exiting the app.

**PS: I'm using single Activity pattern with single navigation graph.**

[image]

Comment: Can you please add your navigation graph code here?

Comment: @Android Geek I've added the graph, do you still need the code?

Comment: You should never be using login or splash screens as the start destination of your graph as per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination). There's a whole API [specifically for implement splash screens correctly](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen). Is there a reason you aren't using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @ianhanniballake, I post my final solution here, the key point is that the `BottomNavigationView` must be the start destination insead of other **[conditional destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional)** like login or splash screen.

---

**Step 1. Create and Setup Splash Layout and Fragment**

- Add `SplashFragment` into Navigation graph.
- No need to create action from `HomeFragment` -> `SplashFragment`, unless you need transition animation

**Step 2. Setup `MainViewModel` (shared `ViewModel`)**

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private var _isFirstLaunch = true  //replace with the real condition in the future

    val isFirstLaunch: Boolean         //will be accessed by SplashFragment and HomeFragment
        get() = _isFirstLaunch

    fun updateIsFirstLaunch(isFirstLaunch: Boolean) {
        _isFirstLaunch = isFirstLaunch
    }
}
```

**Step 3. Setup `HomeFragment`**

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding
    private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel  //shared ViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        if (mainViewModel.isFirstLaunch) {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.splashFragment)   //no need action, unless you want transition animation
        }

        binding.goButton.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_home2Fragment)
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

**Step 4. Setup `SplashFragment`**

```
class SplashFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentSplashBinding
    private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel  //shared ViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_splash, container, false)
        mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        binding.exitSplashButton.setOnClickListener {
            mainViewModel.updateIsFirstLaunch(false)  //update the condition

            findNavController().navigateUp()    //go back to HomeFragment
        } 

        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            requireActivity().finish()
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Demo: https://youtu.be/AxiIsY6BtGg

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem as follows:

Сreate 2 navigation graphs:

**navigation/splash_nav_graph.xml** - (there may be a large graph here, for example an authorization flow).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/splash_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/splashFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
        android:name="com.example.SplashFragment"
        android:label="SplashFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_splash">
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

**navigation/bottom_nav_graph.xml** - main graph ([by example](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/home_graph">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/fragment1"/>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/fragment2"/>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/fragment3"/>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/fragment4"/>

</navigation>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<ViewGroup>
...    
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/navHost"
            ...
            />
    
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
            android:visibility="gone"
            ...
            />
</ViewGroup>
```

add **android:visibility="gone"** so that BottomNavigationView is not displayed at start

**MainActivity.kt**

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
       
        private val navController: NavController by lazy {
            val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navHost) as NavHostFragment
            navHostFragment.navController
        }
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            ...
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                navController.setGraph(R.navigation.splash_nav_graph)
            } else {
                startBottomNavigation()
            }
        }
    
    
    fun startBottomNavigation() {
            navController.setGraph(R.navigation.bottom_nav_graph)
        binding.bottomNavigationView.apply {
            isVisible = true
            setupWithNavController(navController)
        }
       
    }
}
```

And then in your SplashFragment (or any other fragment in splash_nav_graph.xml), to go to the main graph:

```
(requireActivity() as MainActivity).startBottomNavigation()
```